# My PHP redirect for mobile isn't working

Tags: php, android, iphone

Help!  I've tried some different code, but nothing works to redirect to mobile.  I am on a godaddy server, and here is my code, in index.php

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
?>
```

---Edit---
This is what I've changed it to.  Try to go easy on me, I don't know much about php.

```
<?php
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone = true) if ($android = true) if ($palmpre = true) if ($ipod =     true) if ($berry = true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
?>
```

----Edit----

Based on something someone else told me to do, this is the new code I've put in...  It still isn't working.

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone == true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
if ($android == true)
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
if ($palmpre == true)
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
if ($ipod == true)
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
if ($berry == true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
?>
```

Comment: `if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true)` that isn't proper syntax. They need to be explicitly done separately.

Comment: Okay, I changed it.  Still doesn't work. :/

Comment: *"Still doesn't work"* That isn't a very good description of what isn't working. You will need to update your post with the code you're using now and post any errors you may be getting by using php's error reporting and how it's being used, if on a hosted or local machine server and how.

Comment: please don't insert code in comments, edit your question instead https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45332461/edit

Comment: *"Try to take it easy on me"* - I don't see where I was being out of line, impolite, or anything else here. I am taking it easy on you. I can't show that I am wearing white gloves right now, because I don't have video conferencing enabled *lol* Edit: Oh, you removed that comment.

Comment: `if ($variable = true)` are assignments, you need to add another `=` sign in there for comparisons. As in `if ($variable == true)`

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that you were being out of line in any way.  Sorry if it came across that way...

Comment: Edited again...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry) === true){ 
header('Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/');
}
```

you need double paranthesis in the if statement, please note the diference between [the operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong, this code would not have run. Your final attempt was syntactically correct, but did not account for the vagaries of [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) which can return `0` in case of a match.

```
<?php
$iphone  = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "webOS");
$berry   = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "BlackBerry");
$ipod    = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPod");

if ($iphone !== false || $android !== false || $palmpre !== false || $ipod !== false || $berry !== false) {
    header("Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/");
}
```

Note the use of strict equality checks; `0 == true` but `0 !== true`.

Though, this is a good use for a regular expression search:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/iphone|android|webos|blackberry|ipod/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    header("Location: http://mobile.practicallunacy.com/");
}
```